# How to get a sublist starting with a certain match and ending with a different match by Java stream API?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am interested in a `stream`y way to get a sublist out of an **ordered** list of objects. The sublist should start with an object matching a given condition concerning one of its attributes and it should end with an object matching a different condition.

Let's say, I have the following class `Element`:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Element implements Comparable<Element> {

    String abbreviation;
    LocalDateTime creationTime;

    public Element(String abbreviation, LocalDateTime creationTime) {
        this.abbreviation = abbreviation;
        this.creationTime = creationTime;
    }

    public String getAbbreviation() {
        return abbreviation;
    }

    public void setAbbreviation(String abbreviation) {
        this.abbreviation = abbreviation;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getCreationTime() {
        return creationTime;
    }

    public void setCreationTime(LocalDateTime creationTime) {
        this.creationTime = creationTime;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Element otherElement) {
        return this.creationTime.compareTo(otherElement.getCreationTime());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[" + abbreviation + ", "
                + creationTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME) + "]";
    }
}
```

I receive a `List<Element>` which is ordered by `creationTime`. Now I want to find out if there are elements between two specific ones only regarding their `abbreviation`. I know how to `filter` single elements or lists of elements matching a given `abbreviation` using `findFirst()` or `findAny()` and `Collectors.toList()`. However, I just don't know how to find a sublist beginning with a certain `abbreviation` and ending with another one because the elements in between do (and should) not match the conditions and there are two different conditions.

Assume I have the following `List<Element>`(-generating method):

```
private static List<Element> generateSomeElements() {
    List<Element> elements = new ArrayList<Element>();

    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();

    Element elementOne = new Element("ABC", now.minus(14, ChronoUnit.DAYS));
    Element elementTwo = new Element("DEF", now.minus(13, ChronoUnit.DAYS));
    Element elementThree = new Element("GHI", now.minus(12, ChronoUnit.DAYS));
    Element elementFour = new Element("JKL", now.minus(11, ChronoUnit.DAYS));
    Element elementFive = new Element("MNO", now.minus(10, ChronoUnit.DAYS));
    Element elementSix = new Element("PQR", now.minus(9, ChronoUnit.DAYS));
    Element elementSeven = new Element("STU", now.minus(8, ChronoUnit.DAYS));
    Element elementEight = new Element("VWX", now.minus(7, ChronoUnit.DAYS));
    Element elementNine = new Element("YZ1", now.minus(6, ChronoUnit.DAYS));
    Element elementTen = new Element("234", now.minus(5, ChronoUnit.DAYS));

    elements.add(elementOne);
    elements.add(elementTwo);
    elements.add(elementThree);
    elements.add(elementFour);
    elements.add(elementFive);
    elements.add(elementSix);
    elements.add(elementSeven);
    elements.add(elementEight);
    elements.add(elementNine);
    elements.add(elementTen);

    return elements;
}
```

**I need the sublist from (including) `"MNO"` to (including) `"YZ1"` keeping the order it has in the source list, leaving the `creationTime` aside**.

I know how to do that without using streams (like finding indexes of *start* and  *end* and then getting the elements from index `start` to index `end`), which might be sufficient but is somehow *old-fashioned* and not really satisfying my greed for utilizing modern APIs.

I could add the ways I made it work, but they would just be another form of describing the problem which I am not able to resolve using a single stream-statement. In addition, those ways are explained in a multitude of different questions asking for a general possibility and not targeting stream API.

> **In general:**
>   There are two conditions and a `List<Element>` where a sublist is to be collected whose first element is the one matching condition 1 and whose last element it the one matching condition 2 while all elements between those are collected, too, and the order stays as it is in the origin.

**So if you know a possibility of getting the desired sublist with a single stream API statement, please add it as an answer.**

I will have a look at the `reduce()` method in the meantime, maybe that is the answer to the mystery…

**EDIT**
I found a solution which gives me the desired result using `stream()` calls, but I need three of them. One which fetches the element that matches the first condition, a second one that finds the matching element for the second condition and then one which fetches the desired sublist using the `creationTime`s of the two elements that were found in the first two `stream()`s:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Element> elements = generateSomeElements();

    // print origin once followed by a horizontal separator for the human eye
    elements.forEach(element -> System.out.println(element.toString()));

    System.out.println("————————————————————————————————");

    // find the reference object which should be the first element of the desired
    // sublist
    Element fromIncluding = elements.stream()
            .filter(element -> element.getAbbreviation().equals("MNO")).findFirst()
            .get();
    Element toIncluding = elements.stream()
            .filter(element -> element.getAbbreviation().equals("YZ1")).findFirst()
            .get();

    List<Element> mnoToYz1 = elements.stream()
            .filter(element ->
                (element.getCreationTime().isAfter(fromIncluding.getCreationTime())
                    && element.getCreationTime().isBefore(toIncluding.getCreationTime()))
                || element.getCreationTime().isEqual(fromIncluding.getCreationTime())
                || element.getCreationTime().isEqual(toIncluding.getCreationTime()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    mnoToYz1.forEach(element -> System.out.println(element.toString()));
}
```

Comment: Doubt: are you really bothered about `abbreviation` set or the `creationTime` duration while filtering?

Comment: I meant, if I simply phrase it as `List<Element> mnoToYz1sss = elements.stream()
            .takeWhile(element -> element.getCreationTime().compareTo(fromIncluding) >= 0)
            .dropWhile(element -> element.getCreationTime().compareTo(toIncluding) <= 0)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());` .. using variables from your last code, does this solve the current purpose?

Comment: @nullpointer I cannot / don't want to use the `takeWhile` method, that's why it does not resolve my purpose. I found a way using the `creationTime` and edited that one in, but the question still stays asking about how to do it using the `abbreviation` and not fetching the two elements before the stream.

Comment: I think the way to solve it with an imperative approach would also require at least two `while` loops. So there isn't anything wrong with your current solution as well. Apart from the fact that the `||` conditions don't look very firm in checking a specific duration.

Comment: @nullpointer OK, I think so, too. I might answer this question myself if I find a possibility.

Comment: Do you absolutely need to use `stream` APIs? If not, you can simply use `subList` after getting the two indexes.

Comment: @AndySug I don't absolutely need to use `stream`, but I want to know if it is possible using `stream`. I already have a solution that works, so nothing keeps me from being productive at the moment, but I am still interested in an acceptable answer to this question ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the input list is ordered, another way to get the `subList` would be using the range instead of the object comparison in your example as :

```
int fromIncluding = IntStream.range(0, elements.size())
    .filter(i -> elements.get(i).getAbbreviation().equals("MNO"))
    .findFirst().orElse(0);
int toIncluding = IntStream.range(fromIncluding, elements.size())
    .filter(i -> elements.get(i).getAbbreviation().equals("YZ1"))
    .findFirst().orElse(elements.size() - 1);

List<Element> mnoToYz1 = elements.subList(fromIncluding, toIncluding+1);
```

Comment: But do keep in mind this doesn't perform a duration check as you do in your sample. Which in my understanding is not required according to your question as well.

Comment: Perhaps use `IntStream.range(fromIncluding, elements.size())` for the second stream.

Comment: Best answer, accepted although more streams needed than the desired single one. I think it is not really possible with a single stream statement.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need `takeWhile` / `dropWhile` methods on the stream. Take a look at [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library by [Tagir Valeev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4856258/tagir-valeev)

Comment: Thank you for suggesting that library, but I really don't want to include more external libraries than I already have. This is a useful answer anyway, might help me in future projects.

Comment: @deHaar The `takeWhile` and `dropWhile` operations were added to streams in Java 9.